# Smart banner in nuxt.js

Tags: nuxt.js, smartbanner, smart-app-banner

I have an nuxt project and I want to add app banner like smart app banner. But smart app banner just works on Safari, not in other browsers. Which app banner package can I use that works on all browsers?

In app.html, I add these codes
`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/smart-app-banner/dist/smart-app-banner.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

`

`<script src="node_modules/smart-app-banner/dist/smart-app-banner.js"></script>`
`<script> new SmartBanner({ title: 'xx', author: null, price: 'FREE', appStoreLanguage: 'us', inAppStore: 'FREE',  inGooglePlay: 'FREE',  inAmazonAppStore: 'In the Amazon Appstore', inWindowsStore: 'In the Windows Store',  GooglePlayParams: null,  icon: null,  iconGloss: null,  url: null,  button: 'VIEW',  scale: 'auto',  speedIn: 300,  speedOut: 400,  daysHidden: 0,  daysReminder: 0,  force: null,  hideOnInstall: false, layer: false, iOSUniversalApp: true, appendToSelector: 'body',  onInstall: function() { // alert('Click install'); }, onClose: function() { // alert('Click close'); } }); </script>`

I want this output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWM9U.png)